# Show/hide element without inline Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show/hide an element with raw Javascript when a radio button has a specific value.  I can get it to work with inline Javascript, but I want to try and do it using the addEventListener method.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <label for="petType">Type of Pet: </label>Cat<input" class="radio" name="petType" type="radio" id="petType" value="cat">Dog<input class="radio" name="petType" id="petType" type="radio" value="dog">Other<input class="radio" name="petType" id="petType" type="radio" value="other">
        <label for="state">Breed:</label>
        <select id="breed">
          <option>Shiba Inus</option>
          <option>Pembroke Welsh Corgi</option>
          <option>Boxer</option>
          <option>English Bulldog</option>

        </select>
```

Here is the Javascript I am using to get it to run while using the inline function, with the handler onchange="asdf(this.value)" in my HTML.

```
 function asdf(x) {
     var breed = document.getElementById('breed');
  if (dog == "dog") {
    breed.style.display = "inline";

  }
  else {
    breed.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
 function asdf(x) {
     var breed = document.getElementById('breed');
  if (dog == "dog") {
    breed.style.display = "inline";

  }
  else {
    breed.style.display = "none";
  }
}

var typeOfPet = getElementsByName('petType');

typeOfPet.addEventListener('change', asdf, false);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ePDx9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #1: `dog` is never defined. I believe you want to check if the value of the changed element is dog, so you should do this instead:

```
if (this.value == "dog") {
```

Problem #2: `getElementsByName` needs to be called as a method of another object (usually document)

```
var typeOfPet = document.getElementsByName('petType');
```

Problem #3: `AddEventListener` should have a lowercase a. It also can't be applied to a node collection, which getElementsByName returns. You should loop through each element instead.

```
for(var i = typeOfPet.length; i--;) {
    typeOfPet[i].addEventListener('change', asdf, false);
}
```

Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/nderscore/ePDx9/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 function asdf(x) {
     var breed = document.getElementById('breed');
     if (this.value === "dog") { //Look for this.value for dog.
         breed.style.display = "inline";

     } else {
         breed.style.display = "none";
     }
 }

 var typeOfPet = document.getElementsByName('petType'); //Get the elements by name
 for (var i = 0, l = typeOfPet.length; i < l; i++) { //Loop through them
     typeOfPet[i].addEventListener('change', asdf, false); //Bind listener to them each of them.
 }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v9fuc/)**

- getElementsByName is not a standalone method it needs to be applied on document or element.
- getElementsByName returns a node collection (live), so you need to loop though them and apply binding on each of them.
- Casing of addEventListener and binding on the element was incorrect.
- In order to look for the value of current radio just use `this.value` and do the comparison

Comment: This works!  I remember reading somewhere that getElementsByName wouldn't work on its own for some reason.  Why do we have to loop through it?